# How to use CSS filters or colorMatrix to apply VIBRANCE effect to image

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, filter, fabricjs

To set the stage for this question, I will be pasting the definition of `Vibrance` and what makes it differ from regular `Saturation`.

> Vibrance is a smart-tool which cleverly increases the intensity of the more muted colors and leaves the already well-saturated colors alone. It’s sort of like fill light, but for colors. Vibrance also prevents skin tones from becoming overly saturated and unnatural.
>
> Source: https://digital-photography-school.com/vibrance-vs-saturation-in-plain-english/

Currently all CSS filters apply homogeneously and equally to every pixel color value on the image. Is there any way and/or package that can apply so called `smart filters` which applies its filter depending on the current pixel color value that it is applying its filter on?

[image]

Comment: I believe this can be achieved using Gamma-Corrected colorizing from this article.
https://css-tricks.com/color-filters-can-turn-your-gray-skies-blue/ 

But I still don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact formula used in Adobe's vibrance filter appears to be a bit of a mystery, but the Caman.js library actually includes a pretty simple formula for calculating vibrance.

I've built a version of Vibrance for Fabric.js using that same formula and it seems to do the trick. You should find performance quite a bit better than with Caman.js as well since Fabric.js filters support WebGL.

**Update**: For anyone reading this who's interesting in this feature, `Vibrance` is now a built-in filter as of Fabric.js v4.6.0 (http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.Vibrance.html)

[image: Vibrance filter]

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
  backgroundColor: "white"
});

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/51283215722_e949fa76c8_k.jpg", function(img) {
  img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Vibrance({
    vibrance: 0
  }));
  img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Saturation({
    saturation: 0
  }));
  img.applyFilters()
  img.scaleToWidth(350)
  img.set({
    left: 20,
    top: 20
  });
  canvas.add(img)
}, {
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});

function setVibrance(value) {
  var img = canvas.item(0);
  img.filters[0].vibrance = value;
  img.applyFilters();
  canvas.renderAll();
}

function setSaturation(value) {
  var img = canvas.item(0);
  img.filters[1].saturation = value;
  img.applyFilters();
  canvas.renderAll();
}

//start vibrance filter code
(function(global) {

  var fabric = global.fabric || (global.fabric = {}),
    filters = fabric.Image.filters,
    createClass = fabric.util.createClass;

  filters.Vibrance = createClass(filters.BaseFilter, {

    type: 'Vibrance',

    fragmentSource: 'precision highp float;\n' +
      'uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n' +
      'uniform float uVibrance;\n' +
      'varying vec2 vTexCoord;\n' +
      'void main() {\n' +
      'vec4 color = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord);\n' +
      'float max = max(color.r, max(color.g, color.b));\n' +
      'float avg = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;\n' +
      'float amt = (abs(max - avg) * 2.0) * uVibrance;\n' +
      'color.r += max != color.r ? (max - color.r) * amt : 0.00;\n' +
      'color.g += max != color.g ? (max - color.g) * amt : 0.00;\n' +
      'color.b += max != color.b ? (max - color.b) * amt : 0.00;\n' +
      'gl_FragColor = color;\n' +
      '}',

    vibrance: 0,

    mainParameter: 'vibrance',

    applyTo2d: function(options) {
      if (this.vibrance === 0) {
        return;
      }
      var imageData = options.imageData,
        data = imageData.data,
        len = data.length,
        adjust = -this.vibrance,
        i, max, avg, amt;

      for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
        max = Math.max(data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2]);
        avg = (data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2]) / 3;
        amt = ((Math.abs(max - avg) * 2 / 255) * adjust);
        data[i] += max !== data[i] ? (max - data[i]) * amt : 0;
        data[i + 1] += max !== data[i + 1] ? (max - data[i + 1]) * amt : 0;
        data[i + 2] += max !== data[i + 2] ? (max - data[i + 2]) * amt : 0;
      }
    },

    getUniformLocations: function(gl, program) {
      return {
        uVibrance: gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uVibrance'),
      };
    },

    sendUniformData: function(gl, uniformLocations) {
      gl.uniform1f(uniformLocations.uVibrance, -this.vibrance);
    },
  });

  fabric.Image.filters.Vibrance.fromObject = fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter.fromObject;

})(typeof exports !== 'undefined' ? exports : this);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<span>Vibrance</span>
<input type="range" value="0" min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" onchange="setVibrance(this.value)"/>
<span>Saturation</span>
<input type="range" value="0" min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" onchange="setSaturation(this.value)"/>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the Vibrance definition, none of the css filters have this operation. I think you can simulate that mood by other filters
blur()  brightness() contrast() opacity() saturate()

```
img {
  filter: blur(5px) brightness(10%) saturate(10%);
   }
```

This is just an example